# How could I properly work with Scala Play Read?

Tags: json, scala, play-json

According to this documentation (official):

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

I have to create a case class, after that I have to create a JsonReader:

```scala
val nameReads: Reads[String] = (JsPath \ "name").read[String]
```

then

```scala
val nameResult: JsResult[String] = json.validate[String](nameReads)
```

So, the result would be into nameResult and it was expecting that data was accessible like this:

```scala
println(nameResult.name)
```

---

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It doesn't print results or return them.
First of all I work with `Future` and read JSON from web

```scala
implicit val context = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val userReads: Reads[User] = (
  (JsPath  \ "id").read[Int] and
  (JsPath  \ "login").read[String]
)

val futureResult = wc.url(path).get().map {
  response =>
    response.json.validate[User](userReads)
}

futureResult.map(r => println(r.id, r.login))
```

---

But! This code works, but it isn't in documentation.

```scala
implicit val context = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val userReads: Reads[User] = (
  (JsPath  \ "id").read[Int] and
  (JsPath  \ "login").read[String]
)

val futureResult = wc.url(path).get().map {
  response =>
    UserTest(
      (response.json \ "id").as[String],
      (response.json \ "login").as[String]
    )
}

futureResult.map(r => println(r.id, r.login))
```

Does somebody know why code into documentation doesn't work? What is wrong with it?
Could I use my code?

Comment: One of parameters gets Null but it set as String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `validate[User]` doesn't return a `User` but a `JsResult[User]`. This is because the JSON data might be invalid and your code needs to handle this case. There is an example in the documentation that you have linked to:

```scala
json.validate[Place] match {
  case JsSuccess(place, _) => {
    val _: Place = place
    // do something with place
  }
  case e: JsError => {
    // error handling flow
  }
}
```

Comment: So, I found mistake.
My code didn't work because one of parameters got Null, due to your recommendation I found it.

It turned out that you must set not only type but Null also